# How can i get data from database for dropdownlist in Register Form Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, html.dropdownlistfor, laravel-5.4

back again
i have problem to show list data from database on my register form on laravel 5.4 (AdminLTE form).
Anybody help me?

Coding register.blade.php:

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="title">Pilih Kecamatan:</label>
                    <select name="kecamatan" id="kecamatan" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">--- Pilih Kecamatan ---</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Pilih Desa:</label>
                    <select name="desa" id="desa" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
```

Coding RegisterController.php

```
use RegistersUsers;


public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('adminlte::auth.register');
}


protected $redirectTo = '/home';


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}


protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'username' => 'sometimes|required|max:255|unique:users',
        'email'    => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'phone'    => 'required',
        'alamat'   => 'required',
        'kecamatan'=> 'required',
        'desa'     => 'required',
        'terms'    => 'required',
    ]);
}


protected function create(array $data)
{
    $fields = [
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'phone'    => $data['phone'],
        'alamat'   => $data['alamat'],

    ];
    if (config('auth.providers.users.field','email') === 'username' && isset($data['username'])) {
        $fields['username'] = $data['username'];
    }
    return User::create($fields);
}
```

i need step how to get the data and how to show it on my register fields.
thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller Function:**

```
public function editProfile($id)
{
  $surnames = DB::table('families')->lists('surname'); 
  return view('editprofile', ['surnames' => $surnames]);
}
```

**View :**

```
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname" data-parsley-required="true">
          @foreach ($surnames as $sn) 
          {
            <option value="{{ $sn->surname }}">{{ $sn->surname }}</option>
          }
          @endforeach
        </select>
```

You should go through https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/fetch-dropdown-list-from-database-in-l-52?page=1

Comment: i can't running the program , maybe because of deferent version laravel
i used laravel 5.4 version.

Comment: Did you try the approach I just gave?

Comment: i already did before, but while i running the program error code was
surnames Undefined variable.